# TFS Cannot Reconcile Local Workspace With Server Error

Tags: eclipse, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am using the Eclipse plugin for TFS and it would not let me upload my project file to the TFS folder I created. In an attempt to fix this issue I deleted the folder from TFS.

I am also using Visual Studio 2013 for my C# projects.

After deleting the folder in TFS I am not able to connect to source control from Eclipse and when I log into VS I get an error that says Cannot Reconcile Local Workspace With Server.

I have tried removing all mapping from TFS but when I do it automatically shows back up. I even undeleted the folder that started the issue and still get the same error.

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In my case It solved by doing in IDE==> Eclipse IDE go to help--> Check for Updates--> any Updates regarding to Team foundation server/ Team Server Explorer===> update it and next==> Next==> click to restart ==> close the Eclipse IDE and again open it try to connect to TFS.

Comment: Hmm. IBM IDE...  - anyway it will be eclipse under the hood - but ... what about the eclipse version you are running ? And which version of TFS plugin did you run having the problem and what was the version after the update having no langer described problems?

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem too under Windows and the solution was to use one workspace per IDE, that is, one for Eclipse and another one for all Visual Studios. This way, the TFS plug-in for Eclipse (Team Explorer Everywhere) doesn't interfere with VS and vice-versa.

> I have tried removing all mapping from TFS but when I do it
>   automatically shows back up. I even undeleted the folder that started
>   the issue and still get the same error.

When you see strange things like this, you have to clear the TFS client caches:

For Visual Studios:

- Close all Visual Studio instances.
- Using Windows Explorer:

  - Browse to folder "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation".
  - Delete all subfolders (or look for subfolders named "cache" and delete them).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Mac machine and using Eclipse for connecting with TFS,
I tried uninstalling eclipse, clearing eclipse cache/files from all these below folders

~/Library/Preferences/

~/Library/Application Support/

~/Library/Caches/ Folders

Still the issue was there & it showed below errors

> An internal error occurred during: "Reconciling local TFS workspace".
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.exceptions.PathTooLongException:
>   ExceptionMessage="The specified path, file name, or both are too long.
>   The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and
>   the directory name must be less than 248 characters."
>
> An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing TFS Repository
>   information for http://tfs.xyzcompanyname.com:7071/tfs/DN/".
>   com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.exceptions.PathTooLongException:
>   ExceptionMessage="The specified path, file name, or both are too long.
>   The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and
>   the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Then I followed and looked for the below file/folder

/Users/xyzusername/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Team Foundation/4.0/Cache/

VersionControl.config

This file was always showing the Mapped Paths even if I removed them early. I think this is taking from Mac's cache or from some other loaction.

Then I followed the below steps to remove the workspace association and it worked!!

What you have todo is just Open Team Explorer => go to TFVC Pending changes => Click on Actions => Manage Workspace => Add a new Workspace & remove the existing one (Note: If you have any changes that are still there at your local machine you might want to copy them to a different location, this activity will remove any pending tracking in local). I am attaching the screenshots so that it will be helpful for someone who got a similar issue.

**Step 1:**

[image: TFVC Pending Changes]

**Step 2:**

[image: Manage Workspaces 1]

**Step 3:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and it helped to run Eclipse as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in my mac. I deleted all mapped folders and restarted eclipse. Issue resolved.